# Yamnet audio classification for feature extraction

Tags: python, audio, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, tensorflow-hub

I am currently working on audio classification task and using Yamnet which is a pretrained model from tfhub.. I am using it to extract embeddings from audios and then i use another simple classification model composed of two dense layers, the second model takes as input the embeddings given by yamnet and does the classification.
The problem is that the embeddings given by yamnet are always in a way that the third class have the highest value and it is always the predicted class.
If anyone worked on such issue plz i need ur help and thanks in advance.

I followed this tuto : https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/03/transfer-learning-for-audio-data-with-yamnet.html

Comment: are you using the ESC-50 dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your data are not separated equally between each class. Your model overfits with the "third class" from your dataset. I would consider investigating the possibility of splitting the data for train, validation and testing using the stratified method so that every class is included during training/validation/testing.

Here is a resource of Stratified K fold:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html